# What is the proper test for whether a particular option was chosen significantly more than two other options?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution

I have data in which respondents chose 1 of 3 options. I would like to test whether one of the responses was chosen significantly more frequently than the other two. If there were only two options I could use a one sample binomial test to see if it was chosen more than the constant of 50%, but I am not sure what the appropriate multinomial analog is here.